# Random Forest % Var explained OOB output differs from test dataset results

Tags: r, regression, random-forest, model-selection

I am learning how to use Random Forest in R for regression based on the Boston dataset. I am unsure on which values I should concentrate to evaluate the obtained model, the OOB % Var explained and MSE of the model output, or the results I obtain applying the random forest model to a validation set.

In a first step I split the Boston dataset in a Training and a Validation set

```
require(randomForest)
require(MASS)
attach(Boston)

set.seed(100)
train <- sample(nrow(Boston), 0.7*nrow(Boston), replace = FALSE)
TrainSet <- Boston[train,]
ValidSet <- Boston[-train,]
```

Then perform random forest based on the TrainSet

```
set.seed(100)
Boston.rf <- randomForest(medv ~ ., mtry=6, data = TrainSet, importance = TRUE)
Boston.rf

Call:
 randomForest(formula = medv ~ ., data = TrainSet, mtry = 6, importance = TRUE) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 6

          Mean of squared residuals: 11.23613
                    % Var explained: 86.98
```

In a next step I use the obtained model to predict the variable in the independent validation set and use the results to obtain r-square and the MSE and RMSE of the validation set.

```
predvalidSet <- predict(Boston.rf,ValidSet)
# merge data for regression
totaltest <- cbind(ValidSet,predvalidSet)

reg <-lm(medv~predvalidSet, data=totaltest)
summary(reg)

Call:
lm(formula = medv ~ predvalidSet, data = totaltest)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-16.7753  -1.1570   0.1062   1.7037   7.2186 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -1.87664    0.69482  -2.701  0.00771 ** 
predvalidSet  1.06294    0.02916  36.448  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.861 on 150 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8985,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8979 
F-statistic:  1328 on 1 and 150 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

#Mean squared error test
MSE <- RSS / length(reg$residuals)
MSE
# 7.085578

#root mean squared error
RMSE.valid<- sqrt(mean(reg$residuals^2))
RMSE.valid
# 2.841671
```

The r-square value is higher and MSE and RMSE are lower in the validation set  than the output of the random forest model directly (the OOB % Var explained and MSE).

In general, what values should I choose to evaluate the model and its predictive ability?
I tend towards using the values obtained based on the validation set.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way to calculate the accuracy on the validation data set is not 100% appropriate as your linear regression estimates an intercept (unequal to 0) and a slope (unequal to 1). The way to go is to calculate the out-of-sample residuals as the difference between observed and predicted (from the random forest) and calculate the metrics of interest by hand. Put diffenently, just skip the part involving a linear regression.

So following your code, you can obtain the "correct" validation results by something like

```
res <- ValidSet$medv - predvalidSet

# RMSE
sqrt(mean(res^2)) # 2.922392

# R-squared
1 - var(res) / var(ValidSet$medv) # 0.8953902
```

In this case, the out-of-bag R-squared is a bit lower than the one evaluated on the validation data. This is not a big deal as the Boston data set is small.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Based on this example the difference between the out-of-bag R-squared and that one evaluated based on the validation data differ only marginaly, but the difference in the MSE is larger. Do I understand correctly that the values based on the OOB sample are good for evaluating the model fit and for tuning the model (best mtry value) and the results obtained based on the validation data are used for evaluating the predictive ability of the model?

Comment: OOB error is only useful for checking whether you have the appropriate number of trees (i.e., the OOB error needs to have stabilized). For optimizing the mtry value, OOB error is not a good measure, as it will be a more optimistic estimate of test error with higher values of mtry (OOB error tends to be a better estimate of test error for random forests, which have mtry < p, than for bagged ensembles, which have mtry = p).